# Flutter Local notification, navigate to a tabview, then open a dialog

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter_local_notifications to get a reminder that should navigate to a specific tabview and then pop up a dialog after the tabview is loaded in the background. I can't seem to get this combination working no matter how I try.

Here's how I'm doing this now, in my main.dart:

```
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('molecule');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
    );
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

    super.initState();
  }
```

```
  Future selectNotification(String notification) async {
    switch (notification) {
      case "log energy level":
        // push the home tabview in (basically, the entire scaffold and disabling animation)
        navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacement(
          PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, a1, a2) => Home()),
        );

        // pop up the dialog which I built in the MyPopupDialog Widget
        // the actual dialog uses AlertDialog in a showDialog()
        navigatorKey.currentState.push(PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (context, a1, a2) => MyPopupDialog(
              refreshAfterDialog: refreshAfterDialog, // a callback to update information in the Home tabview which isn't working right because I don't know how to reference it from main.dart
            )));
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

There's two problems with my current approach here:

1. If I push the home tabview in first, sometimes it doesn't show the alert dialog at all (maybe it's hidden completely due to a race condition for Navigator). If I don't push it in first, the dialog is shown on an undrawn background, basically there is undefined UI drawn behind it, which means if I cancel out of the dialog, then the app just becomes a black screen (see screenshot show fuzzy black border around dialog due to rendering issues).

[image: screenshot showing the background problem in emulator]

2. I can't refer to the refreshAfterDialog function that is implemented in my tabview in Home() because I'm doing the onSelectNotification in main.dart. Should I just use an empty setState(() {}) to rerender it?

What's the right way to handle this? I've also tried moving this code to the Home() tabview but then the initialize doesn't get called and onSelectNotification doesn't callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try using addPostFrameCallback: https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/04/addpostframecallback/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That is a neat trick to pop up the dialog while I'm in the Home() tabview Widget.

However, the flutter_local_notification doc says "If the app has been launched by tapping on a notification created by this plugin, calling initialize is what will trigger the onSelectNotification to trigger to handle the notification that the user tapped on", so it'd need to be something done in the main.dart onSelectNotification callback. Or else how could I get these two pieces to communicate?